# How to use TypeScript with vue and no modules

Tags: typescript, vue.js

In `package.json` I have

```
"devDependencies": {    
   "vue": "2.5.16"
}
```

which gives me `index.d.ts, vue.d.ts` and [so on](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/tree/v2.5.16/types) in `node_modules\vue\types`. At first I had the problem that vue was not found (`(TS) Cannot find name 'Vue'`) when doing something like `new Vue({...});`. After reading [this](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/typescript-is-there-a-type-definition-for-vue2-and-how-to-use-it/1741) thread I fixed it with adding a `custom.d.ts` file:

```
import _vue = require('vue');

declare global {
    const Vue: typeof _vue;
}
```

And referencing it with `/// <reference path="../Declarations/custom.d.ts" />`

Apparently the reason is that vue's declaration are in external module format (using `export`) and global module is needed if no module system is used.

But now IntelliSense gives me: `"(TS) Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature."` and the build fails.

I'm using TypeScript 2.8 with `outFile` and no modules (just `reference` xml comments).

Edit: I thought I found the answer by using

```
const Vue: typeof _vue.default;
```

which makes the errors for the `new Vue()` statement go away. But when I try to declare a variable of type `Vue` I get the `Cannot find name 'Vue'` error again:

```
var app = new Vue({}); // Works
var app2:Vue = new Vue({}); // Doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the basics running with the following inside `custom.d.ts`:

```
import * as _vueIndex from "vue";
import * as _vue from "vue/types/vue";

declare global {
    const Vue: _vueIndex.VueConstructor; // related to vue.d.ts "export const Vue: VueConstructor;"

    namespace Vue {
        //type Vue = typeof _vueIndex.default; // For some reason this becomes VueConstructor interface instead of Vue interface
        type Vue = _vue.Vue;
        type CreateElement = _vueIndex.CreateElement;
        type CombinedVueInstance<Instance extends Vue, Data, Methods, Computed, Props> = _vue.CombinedVueInstance<Instance, Data, Methods, Computed, Props>;
        /*Other interfaces*/
    }
}
```

Now it's possible to do something like:

```
var app: Vue.CombinedVueInstance<Vue.Vue, any, VmMethods, any, any> = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    methods: new VmMethods()
});

console.log(app.toggleSidebar()); // toggleSidebar is a public function in VmMethods
console.log(app.nonExisting()); // ReSharper gives correct cannot resolve error but TypeScript still transpiles for some reason, which gives a run time error
```

ReSharper still gives `Symbol Vue cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module` but TypeScript transpiles and runs fine.