# How to use Vue with Typescript, with no complicated build system?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, vue.js

I've spend 2 days experimenting on this, and haven't made any progress so far. I have a very basic ASP.NET Core website, configured for Typescript 2.9. I want my front-end to be very simple, just single vue apps per page, no complicated build systems or components.

I'd like to get some sort of configuration working at the minimum. This is my current tsconfig.json file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "mapRoot": "/js/",
    "module": "esnext",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "compileOnSave": true

}
```

(Note, i've tried modules es6, es5, and none too)

then, in my wwwroot/js folder, i have Site.ts, looks like this:

```
import { Vue } from "./types/vue";

var _mixin: any;
var _vue = new Vue({
    el: '#vueheader',
    mixins: [_mixin],
    data: {
    },
    methods: {},
    mounted: function () {
    },
});
```

and in wwwroot/js/types folder, i have the 5 d.ts files from vue, along with vue.js file. The typescript compiles correctly into a js file, but when i visit the main page, i get error in chrome saying "404, file not found /types/vue"

Here is compiled Site.js:

```
import { Vue } from "./types/vue";
var _mixin;
var _vue = new Vue({
    el: '#vueheader',
    mixins: [_mixin],
    data: {},
    methods: {},
    mounted: function () {
    },
});
//# sourceMappingURL=/js/Site.js.map
```

My html has this link:

Any one have any ideas? Please don't ask me to use a complicated build system like webpack. I don't want to bloat my build process with 600+ dependencies.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you'll need *some* sort of build system for this. Consider the cost of your *time* when picking one.

Comment: well, not excluding the actual type script compiler, of course. Do you mean something else?

Comment: *Please don't ask me to use a complicated build system like webpack.* - that's what you need to do, even if nobody says that. Unless you want to take Webpack's job and rewite all `import` statements to factory functions by hand in compiled files and then concatenate them. Tools exist because they are in demand, not because somebody thought it was a good idea to introduce 600+ dependencies to a project that doesn't need them. If you're using a compiler this doesn't mean you don't need a bundler. It seems to be same problem as in this question, https://stackoverflow.com/q/50642237 .

Comment: TypeScript doesn't need a bundler only if it's written without modules and imports, just like regular ES5, by using global variables to exchange data between files. Nobody uses Vue or other modern frameworks like that because it's impractical, and you will have hard time finding references on how to do this properly... because nobody uses Vue like that.

Comment: I basically only need Vue to be strong-typed. Is there any way to get that functionality without using module system? Besides copy pasting the Vue.d.ts content into each consuming ts file?

Comment: Also, maybe i don't understand how modules work exactly. I'm importing a d.ts file in my site.ts. Why doesn't the typescript compiler produce a file for the d.ts? Only my Site.ts? How is the compiled .js file supposed to import something that is in a d.ts file?

Comment: @Steve The only benefit of using non-modular environment (you need to load a bunch of scripts with <script>) is that you can skip build step. Since you're already using build step, it's unclear why you want to stop halfway. '600+ dependencies' is hardly a good reason. .d.ts only describes module internals, you import it when you import types. But here `Vue` is real class that is imported from .js module. It depends on lbirary TS types if it can be used as a global.

Comment: @Steve Vue cannot be used as a global in TS. It should be used with `import` in TS, and this requires a bundler. Unless you want to write Vue typing files by yourself to support its use in non-modular environment (and I suppose you don't), stick to modules and Webpack - or switch to ES5. Of course, you can do `declare var Vue: any` when using it as a global in TS but this defies the purpose of using TS for type safety.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50163017 helps

Answer (score 0):

This is actually surprisingly simple! I'm basing this off my first Vue TodoMVC style app which used Require.js. You can extrapolate for your own project.

---

The easiest way to do this is to use a loader like Require.js or System.js that doesn't require bundling - all you'd have to do is compile with TypeScript.

Since I'm using Require.js and Vue, here's my `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "vue-tutorial",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/requirejs": "^2.1.28",
    "vue": "^2.1.4"
  }
}
```

Next, I'm going to add a `tsconfig.json`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outFile": "./built/app.js",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom", "es2015"
        ],
        "types": [
            "requirejs"
        ]
    },
    "include": [
        "src"
    ]
}
```

Let's break this down:

- `outFile`: TypeScript will effectively bundle your source code into one file (but not its dependencies!).
- `noImplicitAny`, `strictNullChecks`, `noImplicitThis`: just some specific `--strict` options I highly suggest you turn on at a minimum.
- `module: amd`: AMD is a module format that Require.js understands.
- `moduleResolution: node`: this makes it easy for TypeScript to pick up `.d.ts` files from `node_modules`.
- `esModuleInterop`: this allows us to import Vue using modern syntax.
- `lib`: specifies standard APIs you expect to have at runtime.
- `types`: `.d.ts` files for libraries that we won't necessarily import; we don't import Require.js because we expect it to be globally available.

Now our `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello Vue!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/requirejs@2.3.5/require.js"></script>
    <script src="./built/app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Let's create our first component in `src/components/GreetingComponent.ts`:

```
import Vue from "vue";

export default Vue.extend({
    template: `<div>Hello {{name}}!</div>`,
    props: ["name"],
});
```

Next, let's create an `index.ts`:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import GreetingComponent from "./components/GreetingComponent";

new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    template: `<greeting-component name="Steve"></greeting-component>`,
    components: {
        GreetingComponent
    }
});
```

And finally let's create a bootstrapper to actually import your at `require-config.ts`:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        // JS library dependencies go here.
        // We're using a CDN but you can point to your own assets.
        "vue": "https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16/dist/vue",
    }
});
require(["index"]);
```

To explain:

- `paths` will tell Require.js where to look for Vue and other libraries when you import them with a bare path. You can customize where Require.js will find Vue, but remember that you have to omit the `.js` at the end of the URL.
- that call to `require` at the end will load your `index` module to start up your program.

Run `tsc`, open up `index.html`, and things should just work!

Comment: I ended up getting mine to work without even using require.js. I added the 5 Vue.d.ts files to my project, and made a global.d.ts file, and referenced the vue type files. This gave my typescript compiler access to the types globally, so that i can have strongly typed vue instances.

Comment: Hi Steve, I am trying to do the same thing. Would you mind sharing your global.d.ts file?

Comment: To run `package.json`, you would need `npm` or `yarn`, which needs to be avoided as per the question...

Answer (score 0):

I am using Vue3 and following work for me:

Add a `vue.d.ts`

```
import Vue from "vue"
export = Vue;
export as namespace Vue;
```

Modify `tsconfig.json` settings

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "UMD", 
    "moduleResolution": "node", 
    "esModuleInterop": true, 
    "skipLibCheck": true, 
  }
}
```

My `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "vue": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

My `test.ts`

```
const App = {
    data() {
        return {
            counter: 0,
        };
    },
};

Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

Generated `test.js`

```
var App = {
    data: function () {
        return {
            counter: 0
        };
    }
};
Vue.createApp(App).mount("#app");
```

without error.